# Nginx default configuration file issue

Tags: proxy, redirection, nginx

I'm using NGINX as a proxy server at port 80 and 443 for SSL, Apache at port 8082, and Varnish at port 81.

The reason for using NGINX is to send HTTP and HTTPS requests to Varnish and then Varnish will send it to the Apache server.

Below is my default NGINX configuration file:

```
#Redirect http www to https no-www
server {
server_name _;
access_log off;
 }

#Redirect http no-www to https no-www
server {
// listening to port 80
listen "actual-server-ip";
listen [::]:80;
server_name localhost;
 root /home/maindir;
index index.php;
 access_log off;
 port_in_redirect off;

 location / {
 allow 127.0.0.1;
  auth_basic "Please enter username";
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.passfile1;
     }

  }

 server {
 // listening to port 443 for  https requests
  listen      443 ssl default_server;
  listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
  server_name localhost;
  port_in_redirect off;
  access_log off;
 ssl_certificate /main/ssl/eth0___localhost.pem;
 ssl_certificate_key /main/ssl/eth0___localhost.key;
 ssl_trusted_certificate /main/ssl/eth0___localhost.ca;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_dhparam /root/dhparams.pem;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
  root /home/maindir;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains;  preload";
  add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
   add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
   index index.php index.html index.htm;

 location / {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:81; // to direct requests to varnish
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header HTTPS "on";
     proxy_read_timeout    90;
     proxy_connect_timeout 90;
     proxy_redirect   off;
        }

    location ~ /\.ht {
     deny  all;
       }

      }
```

But I have the following issues:

1. It does not direct HTTP requests to HTTPS
2. it does not direct non-www to www

So, is the following command right:

```
proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:81;
```

to direct requests from NGINX to Varnish or should `127.0.0.1` be the actual server address?
Please, can you give me the right configuration for the default NGINX file?

Answer (score 0):

```
# General HTTP to HTTPS
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name default_server;
        location / {
                return 302 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
}



# NON-WWW to WWW
# place this in your 'server' block for port 443
location / { 
    if ($http_host !~ "^www.domain.com"){ 
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://www.domain.com/$1 redirect; 
    } 
}
```