# NGINX as a reversy proxy for web and SSH

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I wish to have my NGINX as a reverse proxy for 443 and 22, plus redirecting all traffic from 80 to 443.

What is wrong with my configuration?

The NGINX server has two NIC's. 10.0.0.0/8 and 11.0.0.0/8.
The requests come from 10.0.0.0/8.
The target machine is the 11.0.0.11/8 and the NGIX machine is 10.0.0.10/8 and 11.0.0.2/8.

What is wrong with my configuration below? It is a file saved as /etc/nginx/nas

```
stream {

    upstream ssh {
        server 11.0.0.11:22;
    }

    upstream web {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    map $ssl_preread_protocol $upstream {
        default ssh;
        "TLSv1.2" web;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name nas drive;
        proxy_pass $upstream;
        ssl_preread on;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl; 
        server_name nas drive;
    
        location /.well-known {
                alias /var/www/drive/.well-known;
        }
    
        location / {
            proxy_buffers 16 4k;
            proxy_buffer_size 2k;
    
            proxy_set_header        Host $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    
            proxy_pass          https://11.0.0.11:443;
            proxy_read_timeout  90;
        }
    
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/drive/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/drive/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    
        client_max_body_size 10G;
    }
}
```

Comment: That second `server` block looks like it belongs inside an `http { ... }` block. I think you have mashed together a `stream` and `http` reverse proxy, which of course cannot work.

Comment: So, there is no way to make a reverse proxy of ssh and https on the same port?

NGINX does not even recognize the stream block and the streaming module is installed.

Answer (score 0):

See those two answers, your questions have already been discussed:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/293663

https://superuser.com/a/1381601/702447